# Is there any other alternative to template specific exclusion of pages from search

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, search, content-management-system, aem

I have restricted some pages like admin pages from not getting visible in search results.Using the below code

```
map.put("group.1_group.1_property","**jcr:content/cq:template**");
map.put("group.1_group.1_property.1_value","**/apps/MyApp/templates/SampleTemplate**");


map.put("group.1_group.1_property.and","true");
map.put("group.1_group.1_property.operation","unequals");

 final  Query finalQuery = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map),
                    session);
```

which means it is template specific search filtration,means that Im telling the query builder not to display those pages having the above specified template .However the **drawback** is that, in future if we want to restrict more pages, those pages also  must be mapped to the above template. So instead of specifying the template in the map, **can we put any other property in the map**, so that search restriction is not template specific.
Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What other properties do your pages have available (specifically, the admin pages)?  For example, if you have a specific property that you add to your admin pages, or other pages that you could sort on, that could work.  On one site I worked on, we had a property we put into certain content items called hideInNav.  So along those lines, this is how I would do it:

```
map.put("group.1_group.1_property","jcr:content/hideInNav");
map.put("group.1_group.1_property.1_value","/content/somepath/you/want");

map.put("group.1_group.1_property.and","true");
map.put("group.1_group.1_property.operation","unequals");
```

I hope that helps to make sense of it.  Am I understanding it correctly?  If not, please clarify and I'll try to help more.

---------------EDIT-----------------------

If you don't have a custom property, but you know the path these pages are located, and maybe a default property they all have in common (like a jcr:title), you could try doing that instead.  Like this:

```
map.put(1_group.0_path","/content/yoursite");
map.put(2_group.0_type","cq:Page");
map.put(3_group.fulltext","test text");
map.put(3_group.fulltext.relPath","jcr:content/@jcr:title");
```

You can see how this would run on a local query debugger when you have CQ running:

```
http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html?_charset_=UTF-8&query=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4502%2Fcontent%2Fsalesportal%2Fen%2Fmobile%2Fresources.assets.get.json%3Fp.limit%3D7%0D%0A1_group.0_path%3D%2Fcontent%2Fyoursite%0D%0A2_group.0_type%3Dcq%3APage%0D%0A3_group.fulltext%3Dtest+text%0D%0A3_group.fulltext.relPath%3Djcr%3Acontent%2F%40jcr%3Atitle
```

Hopefully that's more helpful.

**EDIT #2**

This is a summary of both my answers, and will hopefully answer your last comment as well.

In order to more fully answer your question (since you're still not quite getting what you want), I dug a little deeper to find the information you need.  Just as a reference, any time you're doing XPath querying, this is a great tool to look at: [JCR Query Usecases - jboss](http://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.12.13-GA/developer/en-US/html/ch-jcr-query-usecases.html#JCR.PropertyExistenceConstraint)

Anyway, you said that you were getting results that didn't include items that were missing the 'hideInNav' property.  Here is how you can get those results, specifically:

```
map.put("1_group.0_path","/content/yoursite");
map.put("2_group.0_type","cq:Page");
map.put("3_group.1_property","jcr:content/hideInNav");
map.put("3_group.1_property.1_value","not");
map.put("3_group.1_property.operation","not");
```

This way, you're searching in the path you want, getting the type of result you want (cq:Page, if that is what you're actually looking for), and you're getting the results that DO NOT HAVE the property 'hideInNav'.

Comment: Thanks for your Nicholaus, I will try with this and let you know          Thanks,                                                                      Balaji

Comment: Yes,you are correct,i followed your first approach,just for your information somehow,the pages configured with hideInNav property are visible in search results and those which are not configured with hideInNav are not coming in search results but it should happen reverse right,well I might have done something wrong from my side ,but thanks for this wonderful approach,cheers

Comment: Ya, the search is now working as expected,today only I have seen your second edit in the answer,thank you very much